# Windows VPN - NO internet access

Tags: windows, windows-7, vpn, pptp, fortinet

I host a network of servers behind a **Fortigate 200a** firewall in the DC.

I connect to those servers via a VPN connection.

**The problem is that when i connect to the VPN, I lose my internet connection on the local PC (windows 7).**

I would like to be connected to the VPN and still surf the web. 
i guess this means to only forward a range of ip to the VPN connection.

**I've read other answers on serverfault, talking about "un-check the 'Use default gateway on remote network' option in your Windows 7 PPTP network connection settings".
When i do that , i get internet access but no access to the servers in the VPN.**

Any idea how to get both working?

- Should i change something on the fortigate 200a config?
- Do i need two networks cards?
- Is there a place in windows to define ip range for the vpn connection?

Answer (score 1):

You need "use default gateway on remote network" unchecked, and you need to manually add routes to the VPN network on your windows workstation.

On the Command Line, do:

```
route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1
```

with your appropriate IP's, where **157.0.0.0** is the *VPN Network (internal LAN on your remote end),* **255.0.0.0** is the *appropriate netmask* and **157.55.80.1** is the *gateway interface (your remote gateway)*